# Cheetah #include not working

Tags: python, flask, cheetah

`#include` doesn't seem to be working, I get a "500 Internal Server Error". I tried the same code without the include, putting all the code in one file, and it works. i'm using the web framwork Flask

header.tmpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>$title</title>

        #for $css in $css_sheets
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../$css">
        #end for
        #for $js in $js_scripts
        <script src="../$js"></script>
        #end for
    </head>
    <body>
```

home.tmpl

```
#include "header.tmpl"
<p id="x">HELLO</p> 
#include "footer.tmpl"
```

footer.tmpl

```
    </body>
</html>
```

engine.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request
from Cheetah.Template import Template

app = Flask(__name__)

css_list = ['css/main.css']
js_list = ['js/main.js']
default_title = 'Default Title'

namespace={
    'css_sheets' : css_list,
    'js_scripts' : js_list,
    'title' : default_title
}

@app.route('/')
def main_route():
    return redirect('/index')

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    namespace['title']= 'THIS IS THE INDEX'
    return render("cheetah/home.tmpl", namespace)

def render(template, context):
    """Helper function to make template rendering less painful."""
    return str(Template(file=template, namespaces=[context]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

A secondary question that i have is about the $css and $js variables in header.tmpl:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../$css">` with $css being set to 'css/main.css' works

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="$css">` with $css being set to '../css/main.css' fails, it reads it as plain text '$css' instead of getting the value of the variable.

why is that?

Comment: *"doesn't seem to be working"*. Please expand on that; what is happening, what did you expect to happen, and if there are any error messages, include those in full.

Comment: by that i mean that I get a "500 Internal Server Error" when i visit the page, and i also tried printing out the parsed template in the "render" method of engine.py but nothing prints out.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add that information. Anything in your log file to shed light on the cause of the 500 error?

Comment: log file? sorry im new to both cheetah and flask, and i dont remember reading anything about a log file being generated

Comment: Enable [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode) and you should get more information as to what goes wrong. A 500 error is not giving us enough info as to what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks for that, it was really helpful. turns out that the path for the #include is relative to the python file (engine.py) and not relative to the template that has the #include (home.tmpl) so it was just not finding the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the path used in the `#include` is not relative to the template that calls it (home.tmpl), which i thought was the case, but rather the python file (engine.py) which in this case are not in the same location, so the program was not finding the files i was trying to include.

```
../web/engine.py
../web/templates/home.tmpl
../web/templates/header.tmpl
../web/templates/footer.tmpl
../web/css/main.css
../web/js/main.js
```